# How can I encrypt a link in order to encrypt the file location and keep it hidden?

Tags: security, authentication, encryption

I don't have a clue of what I have to do in order to fix that and after searching this website it looks like I could get an answer here.

I'm working on a website of a client. He's a marketer and he has digital products and he allows some of them to be downloaded for free.

After they click the download, I send them an email with a link for the download.

My question is: how can I encrypt this link so that the file location remains hidden? The files are usually in video, mp3, or pdf format.

Comment: Why do you want to obscure the file location?  That will help in coming up with suggestions.  Do you want to prevent people from seeing one link, and then inferring the directory structure so they can create links to non-free content?

Comment: It seems like OP is wanting to prevent people from arbitrarily enumerating and accessing proprietary content. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF the files are protected only by not publicising their URLs, this is not good security practise (security through obscurity), particularly if directory browsing is enabled. However, you may not have the option to redesign their website.

The best way is to issue them with some form of token or user name that they present (type in to a web page or supply on the URL) which is verified by the web server and, if successful, the download then starts. A few considerations:

- These tokens (effectively passwords) should be generated randomly (such as through a cryptography standard random number generator)..
- A hash of the token is stored on the server (say using PBKDF2).
- The tokens should time out. Remember that the E-mail sent to the customer is not encrypted and can be intercepted or viewed by many. Similarly, unless the site is accessed over SSL, they are sent unencrypted to the site, too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot encrypt HTML links. By definition, the browser needs to know where to send the user clicking the link. Even if you did obfuscate the links within the HTML, a junior-level security analyst would be able to bypass this 'security' mechanism using a proxy such as Paros.

What you need to do is authenticate users to  your client's site before authorizing them view resources (download your client's files). Programmatically restrict users to see/download only what they should be allowed to access.